# Excel VBA: Sort a worksheet virtually?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with a bunch of rows in no particular order. To speed up my macro I want to sort the entries alphabetically by "Name" (column B). However, my boss doesn't want the sheet actually sorted - god knows why, but he's the boss.

Basically what I would like to do is sort the range, run my macro and then return it to the original order. But because there is no "order" to the original order, I can't simply use a different sorting method.

I know about the quick sort algorithm and I could always split the range into an array of ranges, one entry for each row, then sort that array. But I was wondering if there's a more efficient method?

Comment: The simplest would be to create a copy of the sheet. Do the sorting and other necessary stuff and delete the sheet once done. This way your original sheet remains untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment, here is an example which keeps your original sheet untouched.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1").Copy(Before:=Sheets(1))

    With ws
        .Columns("B:B").Sort key1:=.Range("B1"), order1:=xlAscending

        '
        '~~> Do your stuff
        '
    End With

    '~~> Delete sheet once you are done.       
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add another column to your sheet (permanently or temporarily), that holds a sort index number (numbers sequentially down the sheet).  Once you have done what you need to do, sorting on this extra column will put the data back as it was.